# fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: centos, iptables, redis

Im running centOs 6.3, I installed redis-server via remi repository on my local machine. I can run the redis cli.
  But when I try to connect via php script I get

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I tried running this after disabling the IPtables but even that did not work for me.

here is my iptables rule when it runs

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:6379 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I also tried running following command without success.

```
  setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Edit:  **netstat -tan**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54980               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33000             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33103             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33065             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33070             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33099             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33069             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33058             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33150             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33052             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33140             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:51634         69.59.197.29:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33137             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:44836         65.55.58.184:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33036             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33126             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33138             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33032             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33039             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:58613         74.125.135.125:5222         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33053             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33004             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33134             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33030             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33094             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33056             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33050             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33125             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33098             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33028             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33127             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33047             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33027             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33034             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33025             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33082             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33080             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33096             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33142             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33002             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33003             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33064             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33059             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33107             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33139             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33133             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33132             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33090             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33013             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33076             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33007             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33100             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33144             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33149             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33092             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33119             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:56835         74.125.236.151:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33116             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33008             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33106             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33046             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33062             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33086             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33001             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:39717         69.192.223.144:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33018             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33029             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33010             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33026             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33087             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33120             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33124             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:54740         69.59.197.29:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33019             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33068             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33024             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33084             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:49277         74.125.236.134:443          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33042             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33049             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33057             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        1      0 192.168.11.33:51642         69.59.197.29:80             CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33063             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33041             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33071             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33108             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33067             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:55675         173.194.69.93:443           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33009             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33097             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33102             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33105             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33136             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:47970         74.125.236.131:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33122             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33051             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33115             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33072             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:60243         108.161.188.213:80          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33113             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33040             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33130             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33048             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:47559         74.125.236.134:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33131             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33020             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33095             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:51535         74.125.236.102:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33005             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:37953         192.168.11.11:5222          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33022             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33077             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33101             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:49890         72.246.188.65:80            TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33109             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33055             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33093             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp      609      0 192.168.11.33:51753         69.59.197.29:443            ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33074             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:48157         108.161.189.75:80           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33088             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33079             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33128             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:50195         74.125.236.128:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:54815         115.112.1.4:80              ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33035             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:44316         74.125.236.143:443          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33121             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33075             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33104             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33043             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33143             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:55772         69.59.197.29:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33014             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32999             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33147             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:46212         74.125.236.142:443          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33111             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:59920         192.168.11.1:143            ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33135             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33017             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:39378         69.59.197.21:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:56836         74.125.236.151:80           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33148             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33038             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33006             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33117             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33031             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:47560         74.125.236.134:80           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33129             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33145             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33023             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33081             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33114             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33118             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33123             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:49531         74.125.31.95:80             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33091             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33044             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33083             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33112             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33012             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33061             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:49893         72.246.188.65:80            TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33073             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33054             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33016             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33089             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:60242         108.161.188.213:80          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33033             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33146             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33085             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:51927         69.59.197.29:80             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:22            192.168.11.37:43447         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33037             127.0.0.1:80                ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.11.33:41758         74.125.236.159:80           ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

It got solved @cjc said redis was not listening on 127.0.0.1 ip. In my predis configuration I provided 0.0.0.0 as ip and it started working.